# Boundaries of a definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm not a math major, and I've found myself in need of urgent help dealing with the following integral, pls.

$$ \int_{-2}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx $$

It looks simple at first except the anti derivative becomes undefined at $x=0$. So how do you deal with integrals like this? Also is there any book that deals w integrals like this?

Comment: \int_{-2}^{1} in math mode.

Comment: Try \int_{-2}^1 .

Comment: Ok let me try that, thanks to the both of you!

Comment: When entering formulae two dollar signs uses 'displaystyle' which centres the equation and makes it larger.

Comment: You mean 2 dollar signs on either side?

Comment: Yes - exactly.  I see your question now has an answer too.

Answer (score 6):

Integrals like this where the function isn't defined over the entire domain are called *improper* integrals.

In the case where the point where the function isn't defined is one of the bounds, let's say $b,$ we define $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{t \to b^-} \int_a^t f(x) dx.$ If this limit exists and is finite, the integral converges to that limit, otherwise the integral diverges and has no real value.

In your case, the singularity occurs inside the interval, so we handle this by splitting the integral up:

$$\int_{-2}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \int_{-2}^0 \frac{1}{x^2} dx + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx$$

If both integrals converge, the original integral converges to their sum. Otherwise, it diverges.

So, we evaluate the first integral:

$$\int_{-2}^0 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \lim_{b \to 0^-} \int_{-2}^b \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \lim_{b \to 0^-} \left[-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{b}\right] = \infty$$

Which means that our integral diverges and has no real value.

Answer (score 0):

One way of interpreting $$\int_{-2}^1 \frac{dx}{x^2} $$ is as a sum of two improper integrals: $$\int_{-2}^0 \frac{dx}{x^2} +\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}  \\ = \bigg (-\frac 1x \bigg | _{-2}^0 + \bigg(-\frac 1x \bigg|_0^1 \\ = -\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac 1x -\frac 12 +\lim_{x\to 0^+ }\frac 1x -1 \\ = 2\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 1x -\frac 32 $$ This thing goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: I tried exactly that. So basically integrating the whole thing over the given boundaries is wrong, right?

Comment: It’s not wrong, it’s just that you can’t integrate directly because you have a point in the interval where the function is undefined.

Comment: @Agora Specifically it doesn't work because the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus only applies if the integrand has an antiderivative over the entire interval, which clearly isn't the case if it doesn't exist over the entire integral.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks Tavish & Stephen Donovan.